# How to use an if statement in a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a simple example. I pass name into serv and loop over a dictionary.
So it should print out in the loop when I give serv a name, but I don't know why the else is printing

My code:

```
service = {
        "item1": 22,
        "item2": 31,
    }
def serv(**name):
 selctser = input("pls select your services: ")    

 for ss, sprice in name.items():
     if selctser in ss:
      print (f"Your Services is: {selctser}, and Price is => {sprice}")
     else:
        print('Select good value')
 

allwoedname = ["n1", "n2"]
name = input("Please enter ur name: ")

if name in allwoedname :
    print("Welcone to store booking")
    

else: 
    print("You dont have a login info")


serv(**service)
```

Comment: if this is actually how your code is... make sure you indent properly... your `if selctser in ss:` print statement is not indented properly. Amongst a few other areas.

Comment: You may not care about spelling, spacing and interpunction in English, but you must care about them in Python - code is unforgiving. You pass your dictionary by spreading it, then collect it as keyword arguments, then enter text input in the function and compare that to each of the keys, to see if all of the input is part of one of the keys. That's not what you wanted to do - but it's unclear what exactly you did want to do? Please describe some input and the expected output for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit to improve readability:

```
service = {
    "item1": 22,
    "item2": 31}


def serv(services: dict):
    selected_service = input("PLease select your services: ")

    for ss, price in services.items():
        if selected_service in ss:
            print(f"Your Services is: {selected_service}, and Price is => {price}")
        else:
            print('Select good value')


allowed_names = ["n1", "n2"]
name = input("Please enter ur name: ")

if name in allowed_names:
    print("Welcone to store booking")
else:
    print("You dont have a login info")

serv(service)
```

Let's try to pass "n1" as name and "item2" as service. Console will return this:

```
Please enter ur name: n1
Welcone to store booking
PLease select your services: item2
Select good value
Your Services is: item2, and Price is => 31
```

Let's change service dict:

```
service = {
    "item1": 22,
    "item2": 31,
    "item3": 11,
    "item4": 28}
```

Now I gonna give wrong name and item3, that's what console prints:

```
Please enter ur name: Some name
You dont have a login info
PLease select your services: item3
Select good value
Select good value
Your Services is: item3, and Price is => 11
Select good value
```

As you can see, if condition for name works properly. But condition for service now prints 4 times - 3 times condition not fulfilled and one for true.

It's because you iterate over dict with services and check if statment with each iteration. If I understood your intentions right, you should do something like this instead:

```
def serv(services: dict):
    selected_service = input("PLease select your services: ")

    if selected_service in services.keys():
        print(f"Your Services is: {selected_service}, and Price is => {services[selected_service]}")
    else:
        print('Select good value')
```

Output:

```
Please enter ur name: n2
Welcone to store booking
PLease select your services: item2
Your Services is: item2, and Price is => 31
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention - there is no need to use ** before arguments, since you know how many arguments will be there.

Answer (score 0):

its work without loop, and actually i confuse about why code didnot work with loop,
So i loop here into Key and Value

```
 for ss, sprice in name.items():
```

And ask if the input is in ss <- Key

```
  if selctser in ss:
```

So print the input and price from Value

```
 print (f"Your Services is: {selctser}, and Price is => {sprice}")
```

and this the else

```
else: print('Select good value')
```

Why i get the error or else printed in all way!